# How to use group by without using an aggregation function

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to find the row number of the price while grouping them with respect to their `ProductId`. For `ProductId = 1`, rank of price (where price = 1000) should be smt. For `productId=3`, rank of price (= 1000) should be sth.

- How can I find row number of price for different `productId` in the same table?
- How can I achieve this using group by without aggregation for `Row_number`.

  ```
  ProductId   Price
  -----------------
     1         2000
     1         1600
     1         1000
     2         2200
     2         1000
     2         3250
     3         1000
     3         2500
     3         1750
  ```

So result should be

```
ProductId   Price   PriceRank
------------------------------
    1       1000       3
    2       1000       2
    3       1000       1
```

This is my code:

```
SELECT 
    ProductId,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY price ASC) AS PriceRank
FROM 
    product
WHERE 
    price = 1000
GROUP BY 
    ProductId
```

Comment: what are `smt` and `sth`?

Comment: I dont understand the logic behind PriceRank. Show us db schema, sample data, current and expected output. 
 Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

 [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: You can see sample db and result table above. The idea behind the PriceRank is that I need to find the order of price where it is equal to 1000 for distinct ProductIds

Comment: Your result table doesnt specify how you achive that result. And you need to indicate how you get the order. Dataset doesnt have any intrinsic order, so unless you use `ORDER BY` you cant garanted order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will give you correct result:

```
select * from 
(SELECT ProductId,price,ROW_NUMBER()
OVER (partition by productid order by productid ) AS PriceRank
FROM products) a
WHERE price =1000
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the best way to do it.. but it certainly is ONE way to do it

```
    ;WITH mycte AS (
SELECT
 1 as  ProductId  ,      2000 as  Price
 UNION ALL  SELECT
1 ,        1600
 UNION ALL  SELECT
1 ,        1000
 UNION ALL  SELECT
2 ,        2200
 UNION ALL  SELECT
2 ,        1000
 UNION ALL  SELECT
2 ,        3250
 UNION ALL  SELECT
3 ,        1000
 UNION ALL  SELECT
3  ,       2500
 UNION ALL  SELECT
3 ,        1750
)
,my_rank as (
Select 
ProductId
, Price
,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) rownumber
from mycte

)
,ranking AS (
SELECT 
ProductId
, Price
, rownumber
, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ProductId ORDER BY rownumber) pricerank

FROM my_rank
)
SELECT 
ProductId
, Price
,pricerank 

FROM ranking

WHERE Price = 1000
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
declare @result table(ProductID smallint, Price int, PriceRank smallint)
declare @product table(ProductID smallint, Price int) --replicate your table data
declare @id smallint
--feed table with your data
insert into @product
select ProductId, Price from product

while(exists(select * from @product))
begin
    select top 1 @id = ProductId from @product
    insert into @result
    SELECT 
        ProductId, price,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ProductID) as CountPerGroup
    FROM @product
    WHERE ProductID = @id
    delete from @product where ProductID = @id
end

select * from @result where Price = 1000
```